# PPPoE not working on my router WR841n, but working fine if I dial from my PC

Tags: networking, router, internet, isp, pppoe

I have a modem which I connect to my PC, I can connect to the internet by dialing PPPoE with username/password ISP gave me.

[image]

Today I bought a router so I can share the internet with other computers at my home.

However when I tried dialing on my router, it's not working.

[image]

[image]

I already made sure it's plugged into the WAN port and I gave my ISP a call and they said they're not blocking anything.

Any idea why? Is my router faulty? Unfortunately I don't have another router to test. Thanks for reading and apologize for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the modem was faulty.

Even if the connection from the ISP is fluctuating and drops frequently, it might also be happening because the router is faulty. There are two ways to check for this possibility.

1. If you place your ear next to the router, you may be able to hear a barely audible humming noise that shouldn't normally be there coming from the router's transformer.
2. If the router's transformer is causing problems, the connection from the ISP will drop more and more frequently over time until the router fails completely.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons for this -

1 - The router is faulty

2 - or the connection from your ISP is fluctuating and drops frequently. You can test this by pinging. If you find the connection drops you should rather check with the ISP to resolve it.

Apart from above two check for any loose connection or fault on cable too many joins may also create these problem. I had the same issue and it got resolved only after the cable got replaced.